# How to move specific icons from message tray to top panel in Gnome 3.14?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, icons, gnome-shell

I'm using Fedora 21 with GNOME shell 3.14.
I found an extension called [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) which works well but it moves *all* icons, whereas I need only *specific* ones.

I found an instruction but it seems to be outdated: I tried to use the following code in my own extension:

```
const StatusIconDispatcher = imports.ui.statusIconDispatcher;
function enable() {
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['qbittorrent'] =             'qbittorrent';
}
function disable() {
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['qbittorrent'] = '';
}
function init() {
}
```

The **gnome-tweak-tool** detected it, but after I enabled this extension nothing happened (reboot did not help).

Another way is to activate the above-mentioned TopIcons and somehow (how?) hide unnecessary icons.

Comment: that extension just moves the "system tray" from the bottom, hidden, toolbar to the top, always visible, one. Everything that was showing on the hidden tray will show on the visible one.

Comment: @gcb Well, yes, that's why I am asking for another solution. Or some kind of w/a using TopIcons.